# React Native - iOS - error: 'Google/SignIn.h' file not found

Tags: ios, react-native

i dont have enough experience on iOS and i'm facing this problem. Actually this is a react native Project I tried to do this on my bridging Header.

```html
#import <Google/SignIn.h>
```

When i try to build the app. It will produce an error like this :

```html
error: 'Google/SignIn.h' file not found
```

The header file not found. The SignIn.h is available on Pods folder. 
[image]
Maybe i just dont know how to actually import that file. Do you guys have a solution for this?

Comment: Have you installed the package  `react-native-google-signin`  and follow the instructions in https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-signin

Comment: project in my company try to implement the Google sign in without that library.. actually we use the old one.. this the code on Podfile `pod 'Google/SignIn'`..

Comment: If possible can you try this package https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin and follow the instructions. This work for me on both android and ios. Please carefully follow the instruction. Here the authentication is performed using firebase so setting should be mde accordingly

Comment: oke thanks brother.. i will ttry